# MySQL Grouping from a database

Tags: mysql, sql, database, grouping

I am creating a database that will have occurance, and time of occurance date and hour/min/sec.

```
OCCURANCE   TIME
FAIL        01/01/2014 01:00:00
FAIL        01/01/2014 01:05:00
FAIL        01/01/2014 02:11:11
FAIL        01/01/2014 02:09:00
FAIL        01/01/2014 02:11:11
```

I am trying to find out how many occurances occured each hour within a given time and date range. I want to group them on an hourly basis.

```
select count(*) from table where TIME between '01-01-2014 01:00:00' AND '01-01-2014 03:00:00' GROUP BY(not sure)
```

Expected result

```
Date                   count
01/01/2014 hour 1        2  
01/01/2014 hour 2        3
```

Should I only dump the hours in a column instead of minutes and seconds too? I think this might work, but I am no expert in this.

e.g

```
OCCURANCE     DATE      HOUR
FAIL        01/01/2014    01
FAIL        01/01/2014    01
FAIL        01/01/2014    02
FAIL        01/01/2014    02
FAIL        01/01/2014    02
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select OCCURANCE, date(time), hour(time), count(*) 
from table 
where TIME between '01-01-2014 01:00:00' AND '01-01-2014 03:00:00' 
GROUP BY OCCURANCE, date(time), hour(time)
```

Comment: I tried this, but the result was only one row with a total count. The date(time) and hour(time) cells were blank.

Comment: It didn't work, I tried it a few times. Does the cell have to be in a special format to extract the hour and date from it?

Comment: @LeRay Well, everyone here assumes that your `TIME` column is a `DATETIME` datatype

Comment: Ah, makes so much sense. So do my dates have to be in "yyyy-mm-dd time" format? Also, when I group regarding two columns, "date" and "hour" why doesn't day superseed the "hour" column and just display all the entries in one date? I just need to understand this as I thought I couldnt group more than one columns